# On demand column creation for model in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-postgresql

So, My `models.py` has this model

`class student(models.Model):
    ID = models.CharField(default='DUMMY_ID',primary_key=True,max_length=10)
    Score = models.CharField(default='DUMMY_Score',max_length=150)
    class = models.CharField(default='DUMMY_class',max_length=20)`

and the requirement now is that a user (consider him to be admin/the director of the institute) should be able to add a new column to the database like `section` or `rank` or something.

so is there any way to add a new column to the table dynamically and if yes can you please explain it with an example as I am a beginner at Django.

DOUBT: if there's some way to do this, then will the above models.py have another entry (eg: `rank= models.CharField(default='rank',max_length=20)` after the change is made?
and what data is filled for the previous entries in the new column?

Answer (score 0):

> so is there any way to add a new column to the table dynamically

No.

You can not edit the database on the go, it needs migrations and Django/databases are just not made for this sort of thing. Your application has a bad design if you need to do this. If you explain further why you even need something like this, I can recommend some better design patterns, but for now the "next best thing" is probably `JsonField` that you can fill with random JSON data. So when you need to add rank to a student, you can just dump JSON like this to the `JsonField`:

```
{"rank": "value"}
```

The other way (and probably a bit better) is to create a related model that holds all the extra properties.

```
class student(models.Model):
    ID = models.CharField(default='DUMMY_ID',primary_key=True,max_length=10)
    Score = models.CharField(default='DUMMY_Score',max_length=150)
    class = models.CharField(default='DUMMY_class',max_length=20)

class StudentProperty(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(student)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

And then populate the `StudentProperty` with `rank` being the key and well, value being the `value`. You can create new objects from models dynamically, but not new fields on models.

Comment: The problem is the User should be able to add the column or what you've mentioned after the application is deployed. So, it shouldn't be editing the `models.py` file

Comment: @VinayGuda Yes, that is what I answered to.